# jQuery AJAX, json data becomes key in Django, unable to parse the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

I have the following code, using Crockford's json2 to parse the object into json data.

using chrome dev tool the parsed string is `"{"query":"asd"}"`.

However on the django server side, I keep getting an exception when I try to decode the `post` json data. 
Turns out the parsed json string became a key in the dictionary.

The query dict from the POST became this: `{u'{"query":"asd"}': [u'']}`, the json data became the key and the value became an empty string.

Is there a way to rectify this? so the result would be normal json data when the server receives it.

```
    // convert object to JSON data
    var jsonQuery = JSON.stringify(prod_query); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/company/product/item_search.json/',
        data: jsonQuery,
        success: //do stuff
                   }
        });
    }
});
```

python view

```
query = simplejson.loads(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass [`request.raw_post_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.raw_post_data) to `simplejson.loads`.